# What with the Windows Gamebar compatibility limitations?

Tags: windows-10, windows, xbox-app

I've been using the Windows gamebar for some time now, but I only have one problem with it. It seems that some games aren't detected by it, or they are but it is not brought up properly. With some games, the *only* way to get it to appear is by running said games in windowed or non-fullscreen mode. As soon as I switch back to fullscreen on these games, the gamebar no longer works.

Other games will simply dim/flash a couple of times when I press the gamebar hotkey weather it be from the keyboard or Xbox One controller. Why does the gamebar not respond fully on some games, and why can't I manually add games to the reckognized games list?

I've done some digging online, but most of what I've found isn't very useful. I found the official Microsoft troubleshooting guide [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/7ed48b7a-438b-6748-067f-eebbd3328da8/fix-problems-with-game-bar-on-windows-10&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiqsJ6ayMjUAhURx2MKHS1zDq8QFggRMAE&usg=AFQjCNHdDmXqaC-DY4en9B8J__lauGILnw).

So, in conclusion:

Why doesn't the gamebar seem to work for *most* games?

and

Can I manually configure the gamebar games list?

Comment: I wish this question had an answer... :(

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed for me by updating to Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17723, but I understand if you don't want to do that.

[image: Screenshot from Windows Blogs]

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/07/25/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17723-and-build-18204

Comment: I might give this a try, although I haven't tried the games I've had issues with after recently updating and re-installing Windows 10. If the problems persist, then I may just join the insider program.

Comment: What games are you having problems with?

Comment: Quite a few. The original Halo is the only one I can recall. I no longer have a GPU, so I can't go back to find out precisely which ones they are...

Comment: Game bar is really slow to show up on some games for me as well (including Minecraft and Fortnite). I recently updated to Build 17738, so it might be fixed already. Didn't check though.